# How to delete a whole database from the browser using a query in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Can you please tell me how to delete a whole database from the browser using a query in sqlite  using Phonegap? I tried clearing all cache history, but the database is still there. I think I need to delete the database using a query to delete from the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Clearing cache will not delete your Database**, 
you can clear your localstorage of browser by using `window.localStorage.clear();` in phonegap. [check here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#localStorage) **OR**
If you want to drop your database use this command  `tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE Casepad.CaseTable')`, you just refer this [doc](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Database) of phonegap for more on Database operations.

Comment: I try this but i need t delete DB tables In resources tabs

Comment: can you write that command to delete the table ..I will also write  than i will check

Comment: like this      tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE Casepad.CaseTable')

Comment: Have you tried this? tx.executeSql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MyTable");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17761285/getting-value-after-the-printing-the-value-in-jquery-phonegap

Comment: can you check this question also tis question ..In this value print only zeo

Comment: yes you give me correct solution..can you please check my second question

Comment: will check it later, time to move. :(

Comment: But it simple may be didnot take time .please sir check from morning i am frustrated ..:(